# Get data from previous changeset

Tags: elixir, ecto

I have the set of data for airports tickets:

```
%{
  class: "economy",
  legs: [
    %{date: "2018-08-01", from: ["FRA"], to: ["LON"]},
    %{date: "2018-08-10", from: ["LON"], to: ["FRA"]}
  ],
  passengers: %{adults: 1, children: 0, infants: 0}
}
```

I am using `cast_assoc` for legs:

```
...
|> cast(attrs, [:passengers, :class])
|> cast_assoc(:legs)
...
```

I need to check that the dates in the right order (date of first flight needs to be before the date of second flight).
How can I get the value of date previous changeset?

Comment: Just do a validation _before_ `cast_assoc` using plain Elixir `map`  instead of `Ecto`.

Comment: @mudasobwa Is there really no possibility to do this (validation) into changeset?

Comment: No idea, but I see no reason for ever trying to do it after casting assoc. The assoc _should not be tried at all_, if dates violate rules, that is exactly what Ecto validations are for.

Comment: I'm wondering if you could add a custom ecto validation after `cast_assoc`. This should work as well, shouldnt it?

Comment: @mudasobwa sorry, I don't understand. Do you mean to do custom validation after standard validation? And in case of error use `add_error`?

Comment: @Runquaa exactly, constructing not valid `Ecto.Changeset` is easy: `%{changes | changes: ..., errors: new_errors ++ errors, valid?: false}`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did not know that I can use 'validate_change' on the field like 'legs'.

https://elixirforum.com/t/get-data-from-previous-changeset/15356/2?u=orange-men

Thx to *wmnnd*